# Library for closest point on a polyhedron

Tags: computational-geometry, closest-point

I need to compute a closest point on a nonconvex polyhedron to a given point in 3D space. I need a simple algorithm or library. I search in [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/) but did not find a suitable function and the package is very complicated. I also looked on Mauch's [CPT](https://bitbucket.org/seanmauch/stlib/src/7a4d7b836a73/src/cpt?at=default) (it does not compile) and [gts-cpt](http://code.google.com/p/gts-cpt/) (the result is not correct). I do not need any fast algorithm. The calculation is done only once for the grid during initialization. Simple to implement is MUCH more important to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found that the example http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/examples/AABB_tree/AABB_polyhedron_facet_distance_example.cpp does exactly what I need. How should a non expert like me know that he should search in some AABB I do not know.

Answer (score 4):

A key phrase that will find you the literature is *collision detection* (because one needs to find the closest point to a polyhedral model to detect impending collision).  For example:

> Ponamgi, Manocha, Lin.
>   "Incremental algorithms for collision detection between solid models."
>   ([ACM link](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=218076))

A software package named SWIFT++ is maintained at the Univ. North Carolina:  [SWIFT++ link](http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/SWIFT++/) :

> SWIFT++ is a collision detection package capable of detecting intersection, performing tolerance verification, computing approximate and exact distance, or determining the contacts between pairs of objects in a scene composed of general rigid polyhedral models.

Caveat: None of this is simple or straightforward!

Comment: Yhank you, I upvoted your answer, but I will use in the end what I found below, it was quite hidden to me, because I searched the CGAL documentation several times.